# Querying Min and Max in Rows Result Using Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

How would you query all the fruits matching a given condition, along with the max price of all these fruits:

```rb
Fruits.with_max_price.where(date > '2022')
```

with the following constraints:

- uses Arel
- in a scope returning an `ActiveRelation` (for chaining)

**Fruits**

```
| id | name   | price |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | apple  | 12    |
| 2  | banana | 6     |
| 3  | orange | 18    |
```

**Output**

```
| id | name   | price | max_price |
|----|--------|-------|-----------|
| 1  | apple  | 12    | 18        |
| 2  | banana | 6     | 18        |
| 3  | orange | 18    | 18        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need the overall max price on each row?  It might be cleaner if you just perform two queries, one to get the max, another to get the rows, and then combine them later in your UI later.

```rb
max_price = Fruit.where('date > ?', '2022-01-01').maximum(:price)
fruits = Fruit.where('date > ?', '2022-01-01')
```

Or if your `where` conditions are complicated and you really don't want to have to run those conditions twice in the database, you could just compute the max in Ruby:

```rb
fruits = Fruit.where('date > ?', '2022-01-01')
max_price = fruits.map(&:price).max
```

If we really wanted the work to be done in the database in a single SQL query, then we'd have to do some kind of ugly subquery like:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  price,
  (SELECT MAX(price) FROM fruits) AS max_price
FROM fruits;
```

It's not going to be easy to write that with Arel without including some raw SQL in there somewhere like:

```rb
Fruit.select(:id, :name, :price, '(SELECT MAX(price) FROM fruits) AS max_price')
```

Comment: I think you could use `max_price =Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(Fruit.select(Fruit.arel_table[:price].maximum).arel)` without raw SQL then `Fruit.select(:id, :name, :price, max_price.as('max_price'))` should work and produce an identical query.